# Error inflating class ... in onCreateView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to get rid of one troublesome exception.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryphoto_fragment, null);
...

This line leads to Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class pl.XXX.app.utils.ImageViewZoom
```

and this XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <pl.XXX.app.utils.ImageViewZoom <!-- line #13 -->
        android:id="@+id/mainPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**I've marked the 13th line for you.**

What have I tried? Well, originally I've thought it's the ImageViewZoom error not getting registered properly but it's working when called from another piece of code. Could someone point me in the right direction here please?

**update**
Here is the stack:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
 inflating class pl.XXX.app.utils.ImageViewZoom
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
         at pl.XXX.app.fragments.GalleryPhotoFragment.onCreateView(GalleryPhotoFragment.java:41)
         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:442)
         at pl.XXX.app.GalleryActivity.setPhotosAdapter(GalleryActivity.java:351)
         at pl.XXX.app.GalleryActivity.access$1400(GalleryActivity.java:67)
         at pl.XXX.app.GalleryActivity$GetPhotos.onPostExecute(GalleryActivity.java:543)
         at pl.XXX.app.GalleryActivity$GetPhotos.onPostExecute(GalleryActivity.java:518)
         at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
         at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
         ... 31 more
         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it.sephiroth.android.library.easing.Cubic
         at it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouchBase.<init>(ImageViewTouchBase.java:72)
         at it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch.<init>(ImageViewTouch.java:42)
         at pl.XXX.app.utils.ImageViewZoom.<init>(ImageViewZoom.java:21)
         at pl.XXX.app.utils.ImageViewZoom.<init>(ImageViewZoom.java:17)
         ... 34 more
```

Comment: Are you using Library project??

Comment: view after infalte is `null`?

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes, this is part of the UniversalImageLoader
also the view is not null

Comment: Must check that ImageViewZoom  class is in the <pl.XXX.app.utils package

Comment: It's there, double checked it

Comment: "Error inflating" exceptions usually have a "caused by" exception below them in the stacktrace. Please include it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it.sephiroth.android.library.easing.Cubic
  at it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouchBase.<init>(ImageViewTouchBase.java:72)
  at it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch.<init>(ImageViewTouch.java:42)
  at pl.XXX.app.utils.ImageViewZoom.<init>(ImageViewZoom.java:21)
  at pl.XXX.app.utils.ImageViewZoom.<init>(ImageViewZoom.java:17)
```

Your `ImageViewZoom` constructor eventually calls `ImageViewTouchBase` constructor which `it.sephiroth.android.library.easing.Cubic` that cannot be found. Make sure the code is included in your project.

Comment: That's probably the right direction. This is included in my project though as a dependency for ImageViewZoom

Comment: Forgot to change this library to... a library module. Thanks!

Comment: @Messer could you please give a little more details as to how you've resolved this issue?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the library wasn't imported into my project correctly. What's your situation/problem?